# Fill array starting from negative number

Tags: c#, windows

The array consists of 100 items. I need to initialize elements of the array which sequential numbers starting from -2.

Comment: you can always start an array with a negative number as the first element but if you are referring to the index then it won't. the first index of the collection is always 0.

Comment: why do you want to start array index from -2?

Comment: If it's really necessary, you could create a class with an indexer to enable this syntax.

Comment: @user2233913, what is the -4th character in your name?

Answer (score 7):

You mean `SomeArray[-2]`? It's not possible, as a value inside `[ ]` brackets are indexes, and it they can't be negative numbers (but the index starts from 0)... It's like having minus 2nd apple in your basket.

But if you mean values, you can do it easily by a loop

```
for (i=0; i<=100; i++) {
    SomeArray[i] = i-2;
}
```

Comment: Or `Enumerable.Range(-2,100)`

Comment: I meant not indexes, but values, as i have written in the question. thaks a lot, Pablo Lemurr. that was i couldn't get.

Comment: @user2233913 If that's answered the question, you should click the tick on the left to mark it solved.

Comment: +1 as it actually answers the question... But you can create "array" with negative indexes (i.e. 21 elements -10..10 using [Array.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb3cfh7k.aspx) like `Array.CreateInstance( typeof(Int32), new []{21}, new []{-10})`), but it can't be used in C# with regular indexing (only with iterator or `GetValue` call)